# Given a ISO 8601 date/time, how to use JS date() to get the day of the week (0-6)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

Given a datetime string like so:

```
mystring = '2012-10-23T02:40:59Z'
```

I need to be able to get the day of the week (0-6) from the string.

How can I pass the above to JS so I can do something like so:

```
var d = new Date(mystring);
var n = d.getDay();
console.log(n)
```

where n returns 0-6.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Date object should be able to [parse the ISO 8601 format in ECMA-262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), it does not work reliably across browsers so you are much better off to parse them manually:

```
function isoStringToDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3]||0, b[4]||0, b[5]||0, b[6]||0));
}
```

You can then use the [`getDay`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.16) method to get the day number (Sunday = 0, Saturday = 6):

```
isoStringToDate('2012-10-23T02:40:59Z').getDay(); // 2 for me
```

Comment: This unfortunatelly doesn't work with 20121023T024059Z, which [is also ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and is used e.g. in ical.

Comment: @Fanky—ECMA-262 only supports one ISO 8601 format, it doesn't support all formats generally.

Answer (score 0):

Do what you proposed!

[`Date - getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

> Returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time.